# iphone SDK: How to use the checkmark to delete the row is checked?

Tags: iphone, sdk, tableview

I only know the first step is to check a row.
Next I think is use a `NSMutableArray` to record which row is been checked,
and this is my code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){

                [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
            }

            else {

                [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

        }
    }
```

So, my question is:

1. How to put this checked row's indexPath into a Array?
2. How to add a delete button that I can delete all the row I selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off declare a NSMutableArray in youre viewController's .h file.

Like so:

```
NSMutableArray *checkedRows;
```

Change youre didSelectRow method like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([checkedRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [checkedRows removeObject:indexPath];
    }
    else {
        [checkedRows addObject:indexpath];
    }
    [self.tableView beginUpdates]; //Just for animation..
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

And in youre cellForRow method add this:

```
if ([checkedRows containsObject:indexPath]){
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: soory,I got null when I Log checkedRows ...?

Comment: Sorry i didnt notice the second part of the question.. This will only handle checking the rows..

The reason checkedRows is null is probaly because you didnt allocate it in viewDidLoad.. Like: checkedRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
also release it in dealloc [checkedRows release];

Do something like TechZen recomended..

Comment: OK,I can get a checkedRows = [ s, r],s means Section,r means Rows.

Answer (score 1):

You are going about this wrong.

You don't handle the editing accessory views yourself. Instead, you send `setEditing:animated:` to the table and it alters the cells for you. Then you need to implement:

```
– tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: 
– tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:
```

... to actually remove the row cells.